# PIL's .crop returns image 0x0. So does ImageGrab.grab with specified bbox

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

so I am trying to capture a part of my screen. But it returns me 0x0 image. All my code at the moment is:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(466,789,116,439))
print im
>><PIL.Image._ImageCrop image mode=RGB size=0x0 at 0x1E64120>
```

Although without specifying bbox

```
im = ImageGrab.grab()
print im
>><PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=1280x1024 at 0x1F33198>
```

I also tried to take a fullscreen image and then crop it:

```
bbox=(466,789,116,439)
im = ImageGrab.grab()
print im
im = im.crop((466,789,116,439))
print im
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=1280x1024 at 0x1DA41C0>
<PIL.Image._ImageCrop image mode=RGB size=0x0 at 0x1DA4260>
```

I have literally no idea how it is not working. Haven't found anyone with the same problem, so here I am.
Thanks in advance

Python 2.7
PIL 1.1.7

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with this and realized that the bbox is (start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y) instead of (x, y, width, height) so supposing those parameters are your dimensions just write

```
im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(466,789,582,1228))
```

and you should have a correctly sized image.